# How to start Ubuntu installer in a graphical safe mode?

Tags: software-installation, intel-graphics

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 on a Dell OPTIPLEX 3010 IvyBridge and when I start the setup, the screen goes awry with a lot of colored patterns.

Is there a way to start the installer in text mode or a graphical safe-mode?

On Ubuntu 11.04, it works well.

Comment: To boot in a graphical "safe mode", enable the "nomodeset" option on the boot screen (press F6, use arrow keys and enter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Alternate install CD](http://ubuntu.virginmedia.com/releases/11.10/).  Its text based install, but the final outcome is the same as the live CD.

Comment: Yes, I found there are 3 installers: Server, Desktop, Alternate. So it install XWindows same as desktop version?

Comment: Here is the link: http://ubuntu.virginmedia.com/releases/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso