# Can't install Ubuntu, no suitable graphics mode found

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.2, put it onto a flashdrive, booted from the drive and I am greeted with:

```
No suitable graphics mode found.
Booting in blind mode.
```

Needless to say, I can't install. Booting the "Try Ubuntu" option just yields a black screen. Booting the "Install" option yields a maximized window title bar which is empty and the rest of the screen is another color and empty as well.

Tried so far:
replacing the `quiet splash` with `vga=772` (same result) and `xforcevesa` (doesn't boot through) nor `771` (800x600x256 colors), `788` (800x600x16bit), `789` (800x600x24bit) `869` (1152x720x256)

The hardware of the PC is all right, Itt's a monitor, not a TV and I have Windows installed right now and had video output before installing any graphics drivers.

The problem started in Ubuntu when changing a GeForce 570 to a 780 GTX.

I've tried [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181318/how-to-start-ubuntu-installer-in-a-graphical-safe-mode) but there is no alternate installer for 14.04

Comment: Yup, that yielded a couple of messages https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FC3E445BC9837B53!142949&authkey=!ADZ1B2QJeypAgZg&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Comment: My security settings don't allow me to see that output (all flash and javascript.  Could you paste the output of the logs to http://paste.ubuntu.com instead?

Comment: No Flash whatsoever (who uses Flash nowadays anyway?). But JavaScript. And it's a screenshot. I hope I haven't made any typos http://paste.ubuntu.com/10660460/

Comment: I have no clue any more...  so a hardware "solution": what happens if you yank the 780 out of the PC (or disable in BIOS) install with the iGPU and then add it again and use http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers to install the drivers?

Comment: Can't. The CPU doesn't have any graphics core and my old 570 with which Ubuntu cooperated is sold.

Comment: Sorry.  Plain out of ideas!  :-(

Comment: Well, thank you for your effort :) I'll wait til 15.04 goes live, afterall it could set it's graphics.